# How do I set up GraalVM environment variable?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, debian, graalvm

I do not know much about PATHs and environment variables on Linux (I use a Debian), so I've had trouble following this tutorial: https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/linux/.

So far, I seem to have been able to add

```
home/mendesmcmg/.rvm/bin:bin/graalvm-ce-java11-21.2.0
```

to my PATH, but when I use `java -version`, this is the output:

```
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

(no GraalVM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

I wasn't familliar with the terminal command `pwd`, so in case there are any beginners too, here's what I did:

1. Downloaded and unziped the GraalVM file to a directory (the commands on the tutorial will work fine).
2. On the terminal, send a `pwd`. This will show you the path you need to put on the environment variable. I'll call it **pwd-path** here, but you will replace it with what comes out of your terminal (without the brackets).
3. Point the PATH environment to the GraalVM file, like this:

   `export PATH=/[pwd-path]/graalvm-ce-java11-21.2.0/bin:$PATH`
4. Set JAVA_HOME environment variable:

   `export JAVA_HOME=/[pwd-path]/graalvm-ce-java11-21.2.0`

(My version was java11-21.2.0, if you used a different one, replace it.)